# Bokeh - Plotting Data with Gaps

Tags: python, bokeh

Is there a way to have Bokeh plot data that has gaps in it? See the below screenshot from a Excel plot for an example. I tried using None values, but it just plotted zero values.

x_data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

y_data = [4, 1, 2, 3,  ,  ,  , 4, 4, 5]

[image: Excel Plot]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `nan` (here I've used `np.nan`, after `import numpy as np`, but `float("nan")` would work as well):

```
>>> y_data = [4, 1, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 4, 4, 5]
>>> x_data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> p1 = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=400)
>>> p1.line(x_data, y_data, size=12, color="blue")
```

gives

[image: demo of gap]